# Cannot open djvu files by qpdfview

Tags: 16.04, djvu

I cannot open `djvu` files by `qpdfview` while `qpdfview-djvu-plugin` is installed. I really like `qpdview` and don't want to use other applications. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that Qt5's QMimeDatabase changed DjVu MIME type from "image/vnd.djvu" to "image/vnd.djvu+multipage". [It's already fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qpdfview/+bug/1515018) in `qpdfview` **`0.4.16`** but it's not yet available in any repository at the time of writing despite being released 9 months ago.

**Workaround** is to build the updated package yourself:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/qpdfview/trunk/0.4.16/+download/qpdfview-0.4.16.tar.gz
sudo apt build-dep qpdfview
apt source qpdfview
cd qpdfview-0.4.14  
uupdate ../qpdfview-0.4.16.tar.gz
cd ../qpdfview-0.4.16
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i qpdfview_0.4.16-0ubuntu1_*.deb qpdfview-djvu-plugin_0.4.16-0ubuntu1_*.deb
```

Comment: This is a comment on the answer of int_ua (but I'm not allowed to comment): I have the same problem, but your second command sudo apt build-dep qpdfview gives: Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for qpdfview Can you clarify the instructions? EDIT: OK I figured out that by enabling source repositories as explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302927/apt-get-build-dep-is-unable-to-find-a-source-package-for-emacs24?noredirect=1&lq=1 everything seems to work fine now,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on the answer of int_ua (but I'm not allowed to comment):

On second thoughts this is not so great. For complicated reasons, after doing this it seems I then have the choice of not using qpdfview for ps files, or never being able to install any new packages. I have asked for help with this here:

[suppress removal of "broken" package qpdfview-ps-plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814551/suppress-removal-of-broken-package-qpdfview-ps-plugin)

To echo the original question: I really like qpdfview and don't want to use other applications.